# Connect 90w charger in a laptop in which the charger was 130w

Tags: voltage, charger

Is there any permanent damage on the battery or another part if i used a 90w charger on a 130w laptop?

I need to do this, because my new 130w charger arrives only day 9 and I must continue using the laptop.

**130W**

INPUT: 100-240 V - 2.5 A

OUTPUT: 19.5 V - 6.7 A

**90W**

INPUT: 100-240 V - 1.5 A

OUTPUT: 19.5 V - 4.62 A

Comment: How many volts? I've never seen a 130W charger, so it is possible the 90W may work. 90W is already a lot of heat to dissipate from a laptop.

Comment: I edited the post with new informations about the two chargers.

Comment: I tested it and the laptop turns on and also charges the battery, but even so I was afraid of damaging some part.

Comment: what laptop is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it is not CHARGER, it is an AC-DC adapter.

Then, if the 90-W adapter is of the same brand as the original 130-W adapter, and all are for the same laptop brand and have interchangeable barrel plug, the laptop must be able to detect the adapter properties, and scale down its consumption, and likely limit internal charging rate and limit any turbo modes the laptop can execute. This is the normal case scenario.

Usually a normal laptop will report what kind of power adapter is connected, somewhere in general properties of "ACPI battery", or through some laptop-specific applet.

In worst case your "a laptop" will determine that the 90-W power of this adapter is insufficient and won't accept any charge. Your laptop will operate on internal battery and drain it totally, eventually.

From your comment it looks like you have the normal scenario, so you should be just fine.

Comment: Both brands are dell. When i turn on the laptop, show me this message: You have attached an undersized 90W power adapter to your system, which is less than the recommended 130W power adapter. To continue operating at peak performance, your system may also draw power from the battery. The battery charges only when the power provided by the adapter is greater than the needs of your system.

Comment: The laptop is starting up and the battery is charging normally, I was afraid that even though it might damage some part.

Comment: @DiegoVieira, this means that you are not "operating at peak performance", no gaming or bitcoin mining. The system just gave you a soft warning, which means that it is fully aware of the power situation, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

it shouldn't cause any damage if it is only used to charge your battery. However, if you plug it in and it is supplying power to your laptop and charging it at the same time, depending on the power consumption of your laptop, it might overload the charger and damage it if there isn't any protection in the charger.

Answer (score 3):

The laptop might throw you an error and go in an super energy saving mode. That is, lowest cpu and gpu clock possible, which is very slow.

[image]

If it doesn't. you might go over the rating of the adapter when using the laptop to it's full potential, while charging the battery.

Charging when turned off is not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the laptop power supply doesn't get too hot and is rated for the same voltage (which it is) then its ok use. If its starts to get too hot you may wish to remove it for a while and perhaps allow the charger to cool down to avoid potential damages.

Perhaps best to charge for smaller periods.